# LEFT OUTER JOIN on 3 tables. Why does this SQL code give error 106

Tags: sql, outer-join

Why does the MySQL query below give error

> ## 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'MOZ'

```
SELECT *
FROM GA, MOZ, SF
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOZ ON GA.Page = MOZ.URL
LEFT OUTER JOIN SF ON GA.Page = SF.Address
```

Comment: Omit MOZ, SF after FROM GA

Comment: Use the `,` notation or SQL 92 ansi standard (inner, left join syntax involving on statements) not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rule:  Don't use commas in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM GA LEFT OUTER JOIN
     MOZ
     ON GA.Page = MOZ.URL LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SF
     ON GA.Page = SF.Address;
```

Your version was expressing a full cartesian product between the three tables and *then* trying to do the `left join`s.  The specific problem was that the table aliases were ambiguous because they were defined twice in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear, you have referenced the table `MOZ` twice, choose another alias for the second table:

```
SELECT *
FROM GA, MOZ, SF
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOZ AS moz2 ON GA.Page = MOZ2.URL
LEFT OUTER JOIN SF          ON GA.Page = SF.Address
```

Note that referencing the three table `GA, MOZ, SF` in the `FROM` clause this way will make them cross join and you will get a cartisian product, you have to add a `JOIN` criteria or use a `INNER JOIN` syntax instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
SELECT *
FROM GA
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOZ ON GA.Page = MOZ.URL
LEFT OUTER JOIN SF ON GA.Page = SF.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't include what your joining in the `FROM` clause also

```
SELECT *
FROM GA g
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOZ m ON g.Page = m.URL
LEFT OUTER JOIN SF s ON g.Page = s.Address
```